# Populate a second table from a source table using 3 matching criteria in the source table

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to populate a second table from a source table using 3 matching criteria. This is one of many files that I need to do this on a monthly basis. If I have to include the name manager as one of the options, then I will have to create new "Names" every month. I am not sure.

The sample s/sheet shows the source table and the results table. https://1drv.ms/x/s!An8dvvJR5cTfhLJefK-KPaXujRymkg

Comment: Sorry, but I won't watch a video to try and figure out what you want to do. Can't you describe that in your question? Also, why do you want to avoid the name manager? Please edit your question and provide more detail. If you have a sample file, use an ad-free file sharing service like Dropbox or OneDrive.

Comment: I have amended my question with a link to the sample s/sheet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that you are entering data into a report layout and then you want to report on that report. That is always difficult.

The best-practice approach is to unpivot your source data into a flat table. Then you can build any report you like with just a few clicks.

Ideally, your source data should have columns for

- company
- month
- "type A" ( -- this should be either budget or actual)
- "type B" ( -- this should be Net revenue or Contribution margins or Net earnings)
- value

If your data is in a flat table like this, you can build the report in the top of your sheet and you can build the report in the bottom of your sheet with a pivot table and just a few clicks.

I don't support bad data architecture, so I won't post formulas to convert the top report to the bottom report. The whole idea is just wrong.

If your data input is in the shape of the top report, I strongly suggest you look into Power Query for getting the source table into a format that can be used for follow-on reporting.